# displaying interstitial before app starts

Tags: android, eclipse, admob

I'm new to app development. I'm using eclipse and some combination of xml and java to make my simple apps. I have admob interstitial. 
My question is, how do i display interstitial before menu (main activity ) is displayed?  Right now interstitial shows up 2 seconds after menu.

Comment: Do you really want to annoy your users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a simple splash activity to show the interstitial.
After you are done with the interstitial, or after a delay you can navigate to your main activity.

Comment: i tried that once but after delay interstitial close and i want user to click the x

Comment: I just found out about this - >https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/interstitial?hl=nl   . Have you tried something similar?